# Migrating Data From CosmosDB using Azure Data Factory - Error converting value "MultiHash"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to migrate data from one cosmos db container to another in same subscription using Data factory.

Task Type : - Built-in copy task.
Name:   connectionString
Connect:- via integration runtime   AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime
Authentication method:- Account key | Connection string
Account selection method:-  From Azure subscription
Azure subscription:-    Your existing Azure subscription
Azure Cosmos DB account name:-  Your existing Azure Cosmos DB account name you chose earlier in this lab
Database name:- your dB name

while setting the source part of(ingest) and previewing the data it is throwing some error saying

" One or more errors occurred. Error converting value "MultiHash" to type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKind'. Path 'partitionKey.kind', line 1, position 385. Requested value 'MultiHash' was not found. Activity ID: XXXX-xXXXX-XX"

Comment: MultiHash seems to indicate that either the source or the destination might be using Hierarchical Partition Keys and Azure Data Factory doesn't seem to support it. I'd reach out to them through support.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to Migrate data from the database which has Hierarchical partitioning enabled? If so, Hierarchical partitioning is not yet supported with ADF yet. There is no ETA on this yet.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: no still not available.

Comment: Is there a github issue for this, or something similar that I can monitor? This feature would be very helpful to have.